# How to implement react email to an existing react project through resend?

Tags: reactjs, email

I've been building my portfolio for the past few weeks and I wanted to implement an email automation upon form submission. Instead of using Email.js, I wanted to try [react email](https://react.email/docs/introduction). I tried exploring this since yesterday but I can't seem to make it work.

Can someone explain to me how to implement react email to an existing react project through [Resend](https://resend.com/blog/tailwind-with-react-email)?

I already installed react-email, resend and react-email/components dependencies.

```
npm install react-email
npm install resend
npm install @react-email/components
```